# on the other side vs on the other hand

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I know there was a question like this, but they're not the same.

I've got a sentence:

> Stonehedge, on the other (side/hand), was a permanent symbol of
>   afterlife.

I know that "on the other hand" is widely used but I've also heard "side".

Also, the common usage is

> on one hand, ..., on the other hand, ...

and not

> ..., on the other hand, ...

That's the reason I would choose "on the other side".

So is it correct to use "on the other side"? And which variant suits it better? It's an exam question and I'm trying to figure out if task was correct.

Looking forward to your responses. Thanks.

Comment: Other hand is just right, even in that position. Stonehenge is being compared to some other site.  Side is used when comparing two aspects of one item: On the one side you have her stiff acting, and on the other, you have the breathtaking beauty.of Marilyn Monroe to stare at.

Comment: There is an inconclusive discussion of this on [EnglishForum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/on-the-one-side-on-the-other-side.1209984/). I'd say that 'On the one side' cannot be deemed ungrammatical or illogically formed, but acceptability in English is driven by idiomaticity (what the people choose to say). I could well see that a board of examiners would consider 'on [the] one side' unacceptable as a paraphrase for  'on [the] one hand' in most contexts. I wouldn't consider it acceptable in your example.

Comment: "On the other side": one use of this phrase would be to contrast a series of arguments about, say, a public policy issue, or to contrast opposing points of view.  A very different use from that in the question.

Comment: if you hear someone say "on the one side" it's simply wrong. it's likely a non-native speaker who misheard the idiomatic phrase.  no different than if you hear someone say "sleeping like a tree" rather than "sleeping like a log".  Sure, you could *construct sentences* using that phrase, but it just has utterly nothing to do with the idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'On the one hand... on the other hand' is an *idiom*. That means you can't modify it, you have to use it as it is. Also, I've never seen 'on the one side' used.

Comment: In the text it's used without "on one hand" or any alternatives. 

"Sentence1.. Stonehedge, on the other (hand/side), ..."

Comment: I concur with @AlexWells: The example does not contain the full idiom. So it that case,, is "_on the other hand_" still the right (or even only) choice?